# Android Studio - Genymotion Integration Error

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, adb, genymotion

I am using Ubuntu operating system.
I installed Android Studio and Genymotion. I installed Genymotion plugin from Androis Studio. I created virtual device. When I click the Run button to run my program, I see the following message :

> ADB not responding, if you would like to retry, then plase manually kill "adb, and click "Restart"

Because adb was not installed at my pc, I first installed adb.

I searched how to kill adb and tried following commands:

```
adb stop-server
adb start-server
```

But nothing changed. I saw lots of messages about this issue but non of them worked for me.

- adb installation path: `/usr/bin/adb`
- genymotion installation path: `/home/myname/genymotion`